# Each User has a Personal Blog

Tags: plugins, multisite

Is there a way for a website running Wordpress to have users register, and then each user have their own, personalized blog or page which others can see, or should I use another engine for this, and if so, which?

Comment: This is the default standard behaviour on any WordPress multisite installation, including the popular and widely known wordpress.com service

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is standard multisite behaviour, enable open registration in the network admin panel and visit a multisite blog that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "visit a multisite blog that doesn't exist yet."?

Comment: e.g. visit the URL of one of these personal blogs. If it does not exist, you'll be prompted to create it. Alternately, set up a multisite yourself and visit the network admin panel via the admin toolbar at the top when logged in as a super admin, the UI you'll see should allow you to add new sites